# Can't solve this:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: php, pdo

This is my code, it doesn't like the last line where I call a method from the header file. It claims invalid parameter number even though the method I'm calling takes the same amount of arguments. I don't understand the parameter was not defined part since $params is defined right before the call, and $query is passed a value from another file. I've tried defining $params using the dot operator instead of the plus, but that didn't help. Here's my call to the uploadImage method with the value of $query:

```
Image::uploadImage('postimg', 
   "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid'=>$postid));
```

This file is supposed to upload images from a form in a another file onto imgur.

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

    class Image
    {
        public static function uploadImage($formname,$query,$params)
        {

            $formname = "";
            $response = "";
            $image = "";

            if(file_exists($formname))
            {
                $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$formname]['tmp_name']));
            }
            $options = array('http'=>array(
                'method'=>"POST",
                'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer 8cd9d1bb71401737dc720f9381d8e9763f580af6\n".
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'content'=>$image
            ));

            $context = stream_context_create($options);
            $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
            if ($_FILES[$formname]['size'] > 10240000) {
                die('Image too big, must be 10MB or less!');
            }
            if(file_exists($formname))
            {
                $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);

            }
            $response = json_decode($response);

            //$prearams = array($formname=>$response->data->link);
            //$params = $preparams + $params;
            $params=array(':post‌​id'=>$postid)+array(':postimg'=>$postimg‌​);
            connect::query($query,$params);


        }


    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes form :

```
Image::uploadImage('postimg', 
   "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid'=>$postid));
```

You're asking for `:postimg` and for `:postid` but provide only `$postid`.

Let's solve this by adding the `:postimg` value :

```
Image::uploadImage('postimg', 
    "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg = :postimg WHERE id = :postid", array(':postid' => $postid, ':postimg' => $postimg));
```

Of course, you'll have to populate the `$postimg` value...

And fix this line too :

```
$params=array(':post‌​id'=>$postid)+array(':postimg'=>$posti‌​mg‌​);
```

from the Image::uploadImage() function. Should be :

```
$params = array(':postid' => $params['postid'], ':postimg' => $params['postimg']);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok i tried populating it like this $postimg = connect::query('SELECT postimg FROM dry_posts'); and I got the same error even filling $postimg I still got that error

Comment: Are you sur for what the `$postimg` value is ? Try to `var_dump()` it and check if that's the string you're looking for.

Comment: $postimg is a variable from a form in another file

Comment: Fix this line too : `$params=array(':post‌​id'=>$postid)+array(':postimg'=>$postimg‌​);` from the `Image::uploadImage()` function. Should be : `$params = array(':postid' => $params['postid'], ':postimg' => $params['postimg']);`

Comment: @Bubba Great ! Thanks for validate my answer if it solved your question. Good luck.